# saving and retrieving datetime to mysql date time, it stores previous day's date using TypeOrm, NestJs | Nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I am trying to store pickup_time in **datetime** type mariadb column.
my stack:
NestJS (nodejs), mariadb
It saves one day previous date, heres an example:

Insertion:

```
  "pickup_time": "2021-06-07 01:00:00.000",
```

Getting this:

```
 "2021-06-06T20:00:00.000Z"
```

when I add only date like this:     "2021-06-07", 
it works fine and inserts the date ..     "2021-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"
But I want to be able to store the time as well

I am sure this has been solved previously, I could not find the solution. Any help is much appreciated

I have datetime column, when I save the data it is saved correctly: `2021-03-18 00:00:00`
when I retrieve it using typeorm : `2021-03-17T19:00:00.000Z`

It returns a day less than the one stored. I know this has to do with timezone, I have tried adding timezone into orm config but it's not working can I just get the data back as it is stored in the db please. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this https://phoenixnap.com/kb/change-mysql-time-zone

Comment: @Grumpy I have datetime column, when I save the data it is saved correctly: `2021-03-18 00:00:00`
when I retrieve it using typeorm : `2021-03-17T19:00:00.000Z`

It returns a day less than the one stored. I know this has to do with timezone, I have tried adding timezone into orm config but it's not working can I just get the data back as it is stored in the db please. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

turns out the data was saved just fine, while retrieving we have to map it back to our localString

```
pickup_time: new Date(pickup_time).toLocaleString()
```